# how to float an image left within a paragraph

Tags: css, image, css-float, word-wrap

On the homepage of my developing [ecommerce store](http://67.22.139.249/yarn-store/pc/home.asp) just below the carousel, there is an image under the `H1` "I Wish I Were Knitting..." that has a paragraph sort of wrapped to it.

I have applied a float class to the `img` tag which is located within the `p` tag. I have one line of text floating correctly by removing the bootstrap `img-responsive` class from the `img` tag.

Why won't the full paragraph wrap? I would put markup and CSS in this text here but because this code in question is part of a huge `.asp` system, I wonder if folks would please check out the markup and CSS with the Inspect Element on the page itself where you can see the other code and CSS around it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you added `class="floatleft"` but you need to add the css `float: left;`. Tested using Chrome Dev Tools and it works :).

You can always add the class to your css using the following :

```
.floatleft {
   float: left;
}
```

Then you will only need to change the CSS and not your HTML. Good luck!

Comment: Probably will also want some padding. `padding: 5px;` should do it

Answer (score 0):

I found my main error.  It's an understandable error given the state of my development.  Turns out I was editing the wrong css file.  When I put my css in the correct file, everything worked. I'll examine your kind ideas and observations with appreciation.  Yes, padding will help.